# How to split a number in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am looking for a nice method to split a number with *n* digits in Clojure I have these two methods:

```
 (->> (str 942)
      seq
      (map str)
      (map read-string)) => (9 4 2)
```

and...

```
(defn digits [n]
   (cons 
      (str (mod n 10)) (lazy-seq (positive-numbers (quot n 10)))))

(map read-string (reverse (take 5 (digits 10012)))) => (1 0 0 1 2)
```

Is there a more concise method for doing this type of operation?

Comment: Your can simplify your first method to `(->> 942  str (map (comp read-string str)))`.

Comment: I've added it, and a corresponding abbreviation of your second method, to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29942388/1562315).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A concise version of your first method is

```
(defn digits [n]
  (->> n str (map (comp read-string str))))
```

... and of your second is

```
(defn digits [n]
  (if (pos? n)
    (conj (digits (quot n 10)) (mod n 10) )
    []))
```

**An idiomatic alternative**

```
(defn digits [n]
  (->> n
       (iterate #(quot % 10))
       (take-while pos?)
       (mapv #(mod % 10))
       rseq))
```

For example,

```
(map digits [0 942 -3])
;(nil (9 4 2) nil)
```

- The computation is essentially eager, since the *last* digit *in* is the
  *first* *out*. So we might as well use `mapv` and `rseq` (instead of `map` and `reverse`) to do it faster.
- The function is transducer-ready.
- It works properly only on positive numbers.

Answer (score 10):

You could simply do

`(map #(Character/digit % 10) (str 942))`

EDIT: Adding a function definition

```
(defn digits [number] (map #(Character/digit % 10) (str number)))
```

Usage:

```
(digits 1234)
```

Note: This is concise, but does use java String and Character classes.  An efficient implementation can be written using integer modulo arithmetic, but won't be concise. One such solution similar to Charles' answer would be:

```
(defn numTodigits
  [num]
  (loop [n num res []]
    (if (zero? n)
      res
      (recur (quot n 10) (cons (mod n 10) res)))))
```

[Source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/1dxrxgm8-z4)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about concise, but this one avoids unnecessary inefficiency such as converting to strings and back to integers.

```
(defn digits [n]
  (loop [result (list), n n]
    (if (pos? n)
      (recur (conj result (rem n 10))
             (quot n 10))
      result)))
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive implementation (could be more efficient and less concise, but it shouldn't matter for reasonable numbers).

```
(defn digits [n]
  (when (pos? n)
    (concat (digits (quot n 10))
            [(mod n 10)])))
```

Comment: Need to be careful of running out of stack here when processing very large numbers.

Comment: Building a single item vector just to `concat` is not a very good idea. Since the result of `(mod n 10)` is always a single number, `conj` or `cons` would be better choices.

Comment: @mujuk `cons` or `conj` would build the reverse list. @Charles I agree, I was just trying to write something concise. If the requirement had stated that the inputs may have thousands of digits I wouldn't have used pure recursion.

Comment: @Diego, whether conj would build a forward or reverse list depends on your collection type.

Answer (score 0):

a looping method:

```
 (defn split-numbers [number]
   (loop [itr 0 res [] n number]
     (if (= n 0)
       res
       (recur (inc itr) (concat (vector (mod n 10)) res) (int (/ n 10)))
       )
     )
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest i could find:

```
(->> (str n)
   seq
   (map (comp read-string str)))
```