# Digits back to number again

Tags: clojure

In Clojure it is easy enough to get a list of digits from a number:

```
user=> (digits 234432)
(2 3 4 4 3 2)

user=> (map type (digits 22))
(java.lang.Long java.lang.Long)
```

My question is how to go the other way round - how to create a number from a list of digits?

*EDIT* Good point, here it is:

```
(defn digits [n]
  (->> n str (map (comp read-string str))))
```

It comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929325/how-to-split-a-number-in-clojure)

Comment: Where is the `digits` function defined? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

Two ways I can think of:

Using `reduce`:

```
boot.user=> (reduce (fn [a b] (+ b (* a 10))) 0 '(1 2 3 4 5))
12345
```

Using `clojure.string/join` and `Long/parseLong`

```
boot.user=> (Long/parseLong (clojure.string/join '(1 2 3 4 5)))
12345
```

Note that the behavior of the two ways is not the same if any digit is greater than 9.

If you need support for bigints, you can do this:

```
boot.user=> (def digits (repeat 100 1))
#'boot.user/digits
boot.user=> digits
(1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1)
boot.user=> (reduce (fn [a b] (+ b (* a 10))) 0N digits)
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111N
boot.user=> (bigint (clojure.string/join digits))
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111N
```

Answer (score 1):

also, there is an option to use `read-string` or (preferably for safety) `clojure.edn/read-string`, both from core library. The advantage of this, is that you don't have to think about integer overflow and conversion to bigint, reader would do this for you:

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string (apply str [1 2 3 4 5]))
12345

user> (clojure.edn/read-string (apply str (repeat 20 1)))
11111111111111111111N
```

as an additional feature, it supports every clojure's numeric literal:

float:

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string (apply str [1 3 \. 2 4]))
13.24
```

binary:

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string (apply str "2r" [1 1 0 1]))
13
```

hexadecimal:

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string (apply str "0x" [\f 2 \e 3]))
62179
```

arbitrary (base 5 for example):

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string (apply str "5r" [1 3 2 4]))
214
```

and so on.